# Username and password inside SQL dump

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I downloaded a script a year or so ago. The script comes with a sql file that needs to be imported into a database that you can create with phpmyadmin or the normal process in Cpanel.

After installing the script you need to go the the admin section. There I need a USERNAME and PASSWORD.

Looking at the sql file that came with the script the username is admin@admin.com and the password is a hash value and there are some characters in the salt field.

My question is - How can I change the password to be able to login to the script.

In phpmyadmin I change the admin@admin.com password to 123456 and set it as
MD5 and cleared the salt field

Expected result - Be able to login to the script backend

Actual result - Not happening

Comment: I would expect the default password to be "admin" or "password". however, the password in database is not easy to set, if you don't know how it'll be read, which depends on the script. md5 is a hashing algorithm, that has been long abandoned when it comes to passwords, and there are quite some options. so you should probably look into the script, where the password is set or find out what the original password is and reset that entry in the db

Comment: Don't understand, what is your issue? Can't access the database once dumped on your dbms? Want to change the default password?